# Magento 2: Load customer group by customer group name?

Tags: magento2, customer, group

How to load customer group by customer group name in Magento 2?

I am using below code in M1:

```
$companyClass = 'General';  
$groupObj = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($companyClass, 'customer_group_code');
echo '<pre>'; print_r($groupObj->getData()); echo '</pre>';
```

How to get this on Magento 2?

Answer (score 5):

After review the magento2 code I able to get the below solution:-

```
protected $group;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Group $group,
    ...     
)
{
    ...
    $this->group = $group;
    ...
}
```

Use below code where you want to load the customer group:-

```
$cusGrpCode = 'General';
$groupObj = $this->group;
$existingGroup = $groupObj->load($cusGrpCode, 'customer_group_code');
echo '<pre>'; print_r($existingGroup->getData()); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Model Factory way

We should try with `\Magento\Customer\Model\Group`

dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Weee/Model/TaxTest.php

```
$fixtureGroupCode = 'custom_group';
$fixtureTaxClassId = 3;
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Group $group */
$group = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(\Magento\Customer\Model\Group::class);
$fixtureGroupId = $group->load($fixtureGroupCode, 'customer_group_code')->getId();
```

Avoiding using Object Manager. So, should inject `\Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory` in the constructor.

2) Object Repository:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Customer\Model;   

use Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;

class Test
{
    private $customerGroups;

    protected $groupRepository;

    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    protected $filterBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
    ) {
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    }

    public function testGetGroup()
    {
        $generalFilter[] = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('customer_group_code')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->setValue('General')
            ->create();
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilters($generalFilter)
            ->create();

        if ($this->customerGroups === null) {
            $this->customerGroups = [];
            foreach ($this->groupRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems() as $item) {
                    $this->customerGroups[$item->getId()] = $item->getCode();
            }
        }

       var_dump($this->customerGroups);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * Class Product
*/
class Product
{


/**
 * @var CollectionFactory
 */
private $attributeSetCollection;


/**
 * Product constructor.
 * @param CollectionFactory $attributeSetCollection
 */
public function __construct(
    CollectionFactory $attributeSetCollection
) {
    $this->attributeSetCollection = $attributeSetCollection;
}



/**
 * @param string $attributeSetName
 * @return int
 */
public function getAttributeSetIdByName(string $attributeSetName): int
{
    $attributeSetCollection = $this->attributeSetCollection->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name', $attributeSetName)
        ->getFirstItem();

    return (int) $attributeSetCollection->getAttributeSetId();
}
}
```

We can use the other fields or `*` in the addFieldToSelect.